# Azure Timer Functions - Python: TimeSpan used in CRON settings is not accepting in the binding configuration

Tags: python, azure-functions

Tried the below Azure Python Function binding JSON configuration with "TimeSpan", "timeSpan" & "timespan" but getting error

*Error: The function is in error: Can't figure out which ctor to call.*

```
{
      "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "mytimer",
          "type": "timerTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "timespan": "00:00:01",
          "authLevel": "anonymous"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Refer to Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python#timespan

Comment: Is the function setup to host on App Service Plan?

Comment: Yes, I'm using App Service Plan.

Comment: Can this solve your problem?

Comment: No, "timespan" feature is still not working for python timer functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure like this：

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "00:00:01"
    }
  ]
}
```

I did a test and there seems to be no problem:

[image]

Comment: yes, my current workaround is the same as what you recommended, however just curious to know why documented "timespan" feature is not working for python.

Comment: I think what the documentation says is to set TimeSpan in this form: "schedule": "<TimeSpan>". You can refer to [Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QifS.png)

Comment: Yes, you are right! "schedule": "<TimeSpan>"